# SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 2053 quando chamo uma Stored Procedure?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-4, stored-procedures

Estou a usar `Laravel` 4.2 e estou a chamar uma `Stored Procedure` de uma base de dados no servidor. Localmente funciona tudo bem, mas no servidor, utilizando a mesma BD, dá erro.

A chamada é a seguinte:

```
$result = DB::select('CALL sp_precos_especiais("'.$codigocliente.'", 
                     "'.$codigoartigo.'", "'.$quantidade.'", 
                     "'.$grupo_produto.'", "'.$FirmCode.'")');
```

Ao correr uma listagem, no servidor, ele funciona exceto em dois artigos, dando o seguinte erro:

> Caught exception: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 2053 (SQL: CALL sp_precos_especiais("C000000", "445706049", "1", "146", "75");)

Já verifiquei as versões do `PHP`, e estou a usar 5.6 nos dois sítios. Pode ser algum configuração em especial? *É que a Banco é o mesmo, o local de chamar a `Stored Procedure`, é que é diferente.*

Comment: Sua SP é inserir dados ou retornar (select)?

Comment: @rray, é apenas para ir buscar dados, select

Comment: @pc_oc já tentou executar ela, diretamente no banco, com esses mesmos parâmetros, para observar o que acontece?

Comment: @JefersonAlmeida, sim e funciona. O problema é esse :)

Comment: @pc_oc vc executou exatamente isso `CALL sp_precos_especiais("C000000", "445706049", "1", "146", "75");` e com o mesmo usuário de banco de dados?

Comment: @JefersonAlmeida, sim. Penso que está relacionado com o código do produto, porque ele não devolve nada para este produto, mas localmente devolve um array vazio, e no servidor dá erro.

Comment: Devolver erro no servidor deve estar relacionado com o SQL Mode ou outras configurações. Compare a configuração do SQL MODE do Mysql local e servidor.